# website Hosted on Ec2 not responding, what happened with My instance?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

On Friday I hosted a WordPress site on my micro instance - I installed LAMP stack, and WordPress on it.

Instance state is `Running`, but when I try to access website with public domain given in console, it says

```
web page Not available
```

I have set an `Outbound` rule to allow everyone and `Inbound` rule for my IP address only.

This is about accessing website from outside world, but when I try to connect to my instance with JAVA Interface, MindTerm Web SSH, it says

```
Network connection timeout error
```

Can't figure out anything, Just started working on AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have confused the `Outbound` and `Inbound` rules - `Outbound` means traffic going out *from* the server, while `Inbound` means traffic from the internet *to* the server.

As you say, you added an `Inbound` rule for your IP address only, and you can access the website from you IP only, just like you requested.

Add an `Inbound` rule for port `80` for`0.0.0.0/0`, and you should be able to access the site from other locations as well.

If you need to open it to HTTP and SSH, open it for both for `0.0.0.0/0`:

[image: security-group-screen]

Comment: yes I am confused, I am using t1.micro instance, So I should put 0.0.0.0/0 for both Inbound and outbound on port 80, and what about SSH ports while logging in to Instance. can you suggest config in my case

Comment: I did set these rules wrong, and also `private key` was not converted correctly using `PuttyGen`.

Comment: can I set <virtualHost> in configuration to set particular url to redirect to this site. I saw Tutorial [HERE](http://www.igoy.in/multiple-websites-on-ec2/)

Comment: Are we still talking about the network error? I suggest that you ask a new question regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify your settings and permission based on this :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

You might also want to check your firewall, in case that is blocking the access..

Comment: I will check that link, but why I cant see  my website when I visit using my public domain, instance is running and wordpress website is live

Comment: Can you access your website locally from AWS instance itself?

Comment: I am able to access website from My IP address only. where is the mistake?

Comment: It could be due to anything..try to connect to your instance from any SSH client, and let us know the response..so we can narrow down this..

Comment: I can now connect to Instance using SSH client. but cant access my website which I have set on that instance from outside network.